# laravel 5 behat tests are failing with functions in models

Tags: php, laravel-5, tdd, behat, mink

I’m running against an issue with behat / mink set up on Laravel 5.4 where its failing to return values from functions within models and I am looking for some advise on how i would resolve this issue.

An example on a very basic laravel install follows below:

eg. I have a model called User.php and inside it i have the following function

```
public static function someFunction(){
    return 'A Random Text String';
}
```

within my home.controller i have the following defined for index()

eg

```
/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('home',compact('user'));
}
```

and within the corresponding blade file i have the following

```
{{$user}}   

{{$user->someFunction()}}
```

and i have a feature set up as the following:

```
Scenario: Home Page           # features/hometest.feature:6
    Given I am on the homepage  # FeatureContext::iAmOnHomepage()
    Then I should see "Laravel" # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()

Scenario: Check we can login
    When I go to "/register"
    And I fill in "Name" with "Dave"
    And I fill in "E-Mail Address" with "Dave@dave.com"
    And I fill in "Password" with "password"
    And I fill in "Confirm Password" with "password"
    And I press "Register"
    And I should see "You are logged in!"

Scenario: Check we can access the homepage as Dave
    Given I am logged in as Dave
    When I go to "/home"
    And I should see "A Random Text String"
```

which corresponds to a function within my FeatureContext.php

```
/**
 * @Given /^(?:|I )am logged in as Dave$/
 */
public function iAmLoggedInAsDave()
{
    $this->visit('/login');
    $this->fillField('E-Mail Address', 'dave@dave.com');
    $this->fillField('Password', 'password');
    $this->pressButton('Login');
    $this->printCurrentUrl();
}
```

if i view the above via the browser, i can see

```
{"id":1,"name":"Dave","email":"Dave@dave.com","created_at":"2017-06-30 16:10:39","updated_at":"2017-06-30 16:10:39"}

A Random Text String
```

Which would correspond to a pass for my test.

But when i run behat, within my /home/vagrant/Code/client/client.app directory
../vendor/behat/behat/bin/behat

I get a fail

```
    Scenario: Check we can login       # features/hometest.feature:19
        Given I am logged in as Dave     # FeatureContext::iAmLoggedInAsDave()
            │ http://localhost/home
        When I go to "/home"             # FeatureContext::visit()
        And I should see "A Random Text String" # FeatureContext::assertPageContainsText()
            The text "A Random Text String" was not found anywhere in the text of the current page. (Behat\Mink\Exception\ResponseTextException)
```

and i get the following error in my logs.

Next ErrorException: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::someFunction() (View: /home/vagrant/Code/client/client.app/resources/views/home.blade.php) in /home/vagrant/Code/client/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php:2450

My current development platform is set up using homestead using vagrant.

I have the following within behat.yml

```
default:
    extensions:
        Laracasts\Behat:
            env_path: .env.behat
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            default_session: laravel
            laravel: ~
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything here that's wrong here other then the obvious being
`assertPageContainsText()` failure which is expecting that you have the text being displayed being "Some Function" on your page, do you actually see this?

From the method in your user model, that wouldn't display that as text on the /home page.

Comment: I've modified my question for a bit more clarity.

The someFunction() method within the User model returns a string in this example. The output is rendered in browser, so i can see 'A Random Text String' but within the test its not present. I have the same issue when rendering e.g.,
`{{ $Foo->Bar->fieldname()  }}` and `{{ $user->hasRole('admin') }}`

Comment: I had a similar problem, and I solved it by running
``php artisan config:cache`` try that first and run behat again.

Comment: Thanks @n31l. Not that, sadly. Tests pass if i output `{{ $Foo->fieldname() }}`  but fail when i output `{{ $Foo->Bar->fieldname() }}` - even though these work 'in browser' (with these models bound together via a $this->belongsTo() method within the model). Could this be an issue with behat not liking magic methods?